# Pass an optional list to argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a more elegant way to pass an optional list of integers to `argparse` than to [pass a delimited string and parse it later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866869/241211)? I also have a positional argument.

```
parser.add_argument('--ids', type=int, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('cmd')
```

doesn't work, because `argparse` attempts to grab `cmd` and complains that it isn't an integer.

Ideally, I'd like to execute with one of

```
program.py --ids 6,32,12 refresh
program.py --ids 6 32 12 refresh
```

or something similar, but also be able to

```
program.py refresh
```

Comment: You could parse the string immediately instead of later, by passing an arbitrary callable as the `type`.

Comment: @Kevin a la the [`perfect_square`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) example?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  You could use something like [`operator.methodcaller('split', ',')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) as your `type`, to split on commas automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to parse arguments of the form `--ids 1,2,3` (no whitespace), you can use something like this:

```
def convert(argument):
    return map(int, argument.split(','))  # 3.x: consider wrapping in list()

parser.add_argument('--ids', type=convert)
```

This will not handle arguments separated by whitespace, though you could probably mitigate that somewhat with a smarter `convert()` function.  You would then need to quote them, however, or else the shell would pass them as separate arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`--` is a handy way of saying 'positional arguments start here'.

With your parser, these work:

```
program.py refresh   # sets ids=None
program.py refresh --ids 1 2 3
program.py --ids 1 2 3 -- refresh
```

You could give the `--ids` argument a default (e.g. []) if you don't like the `None`.

Any problems with  `program.py refesh --ids 1,2,3` are due to how the shell splits your command line.  Look at the `sys.argv` list.

Problems with `program.py --ids 1 2 3 refresh` arise because when handling `--ids`, the parser tries to use all strings that follow that aren't obviously flags (e.g. with '-').  It does not use the 'int' type to test which ones to use and which to leave.

Now if the `ids` were positional, it would handle the `1 2 3 refresh`:

```
parser.add_argument('ids',type=int,nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('cmd')
parser.parse_args('1 2 3 refresh'.split())
```

But that's because the parser uses a different strategy to allocate strings to several positional arguments.  It uses a `re` matcher that looks like `A+A`.

---

Kevin's `type` approach might be better implemented with a simple function:

```
def mytype(astring):
    ll = astring.split(',')
    return [int(l) for l in ll]
parser.add_argument('--ids', type=mytype)
```

It could be generalized to handle quoted strings like "1 2 3". `type` can be any function that takes a string, and returns the desired value(s), and raises an error if it can't do the conversion.