# for loop inside def in python doesn't iterate

Tags: python

passing argeparse as us-east-1,us-east-2,us-east-3

```
# Setup commandline arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='using Terraform')
parser.add_argument(
    '-r',
    '--region',
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help='Region in which the ec2 need to be created')
```

and then trying to for loop for in each region

```
for region_1 in ([region]):
  print(region_1)
```

for print(region_1) its prininting all the regions but i want it iteration in loop and print one region at a time. please let me know whatcan be done

Comment: is `region` an iterable?

Comment: How come you are enclosing `region` with brackets. No matter what `region` is, that structure of a for loop will only iterate once. Try `for region_1 in region:`?

Comment: How are you calling your program?  Is `region` a list, or a string with commas in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753721/3949081) solves your question if you want to define better how the arguments should be passed.

For example, you should pass it like `--region 'us-east-1' 'us-east-2' 'us-east-3'`. And define your argument option using `nargs` like:

```py
parser.add_argument(
    '-r',
    '--region', 
    nargs='+',
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help='Region in which the ec2 need to be created' 
)
```

In your case if you want to have a string separated by comma just do:

```py
for r in region.split(","):
  print(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by using `nargs` for the `-r/--regions` in `argparse` like,

```
$ cat arg.py 
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument(
    '-r',
    '--regions', 
    dest='regions',
    nargs='+',
    required=True,
    help='foo bar'
)

args = parser.parse_args()

for region in args.regions:
    print(region)

$ python arg.py -r us_east us_west us_east1
us_east
us_west
us_east1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over a list that contains one element: `region`. `[region]` is a list containing `region` just like `[1]` is a list containing a `1`.

Don't wrap that variable in another list before iterating it:

```
for region_1 in region:
```