# Parsing a list of string using argparser with subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, argparse

I wrote a script that makes some calculation and it receives input parameters using `argparse`.

One of these parameters is a list of file paths.

Looking around I found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/argparse-option-for-passing-a-list-as-option) and I modify my code adding:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Engine')
parser.add_argument('--outputFile', required=True, help='Output file path [str]')
parser.add_argument('--filesList', nargs='+', required=True, help='List of the input files [list of str]')
args = parser.parse_args()

outputFileName = args.outputFile
inputFilesName = args.filesList
```

In this way I can pass all the input parameters even the list of the files typing each one separated by a space, like:

```
--outputFile output.nc
--filesList data/file1.nc data/file2.nc
```

Now I created the GUI for my script and I call the script using `subprocess`:

```
command = [sys.executable,
           'D:/Projects/Calculation/src/modules/Engine.py',
           '--outputFile', self.outputFileName,
           '--filesList', filesPathList]

 p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
```

where `filesPathList` is the list of files path: `['data/file1.nc', 'data/file2.nc']`

The problem is if I run the software in this way, what the engine understand is a list of 1 element: `['data/file1.ncdata/file2.nc']`, essentially `arcparse` fuses together all the paths.

Is there any option I can add to `add_argument` to fix it?

I could change the way to parse the input parameters, but I would like to know if there is a way using `argparse`.

Comment: Try `... '--filesList', *filesPathList]` so the names are placed individually in the `command` list.  Look at that list, and compare it the `sys.argv` list you get from entering the command in the shell.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the suggestion, but I am using Python 2.7 and it doesn't support the starred expression

Comment: Try addi g that liat to `command` wuth `extend`

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks it woks in that way. Now the code is: `command = [..., '--filesList'] command.extend(filesPathList)`, I don't think the code is really clear in this way, but it works and I really appreciate your help.