# specifying a list of list as a command line argument in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I think the question is self explanatory. I would like to use a list of list as a command line argument like so:

```
python3 awesome_code.py --list=[[var1,var2],[var3,v4]..]
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you'll have to do careful quoting to get expressions with [ ] through your average shell.

Comment: It's not exactly possible. Command-line arguments are strings only. You can pass a string that looks like a list, but you'll have to parse it to get a python list out of it.

Comment: `argparse` might be of help, check out similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/argparse-option-for-passing-a-list-as-option)

Comment: @jean Yes! Especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57113295/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

You can use json.loads for this.

```
import json
import sys
l = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
for x in l:
    print(x)
```

```
python3 test.py [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to define a more typical shell command line like this:

```
python3 awesome_code.py --list v1 v2 --list v3 v4
```

Where the result would be

```
[['v1', 'v2'], ['v3', 'v4']]
```

Here is the example code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--list',
    action='append',
    nargs='*',
    )
args = parser.parse_args('--list v1 v2 --list v3 v4'.split())
print(args.list)
```