# Parse a nested list with python argparse

Tags: python, list, argparse

Assume that I am expecting a list of lists where the inner lists have different types and lengths, e. g.,

`[[1, 2], ["foo", "bar"], [3.14, "baz", 20]]`

how can I parse the above list using argparse?

**Most useful questions on stackoverflow:**

Similar questions exist, where most useful one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/argparse-option-for-passing-a-list-as-option). But they are not  good enough in my case as they ignore the fact that the list is nested with different data types and lenghts.

Comment: why not just do https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866869/1358308 but use `json.loads` for the `type` parameter?

Comment: This is what I am doing at the moment. The problem is that then you are required to parse the string, in my example "[[1, 2], ['foo', 'bar'], [3.14, 'baz', 20]]", and extract the data. Hence, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way?

Could you comment how the `type` can be handled with `json.loads`?

Comment: note that using `json` implies that strings are in double quotes, whereas your example has single quotes.  any reason for this?

Comment: No, I revised that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

expanding on my comment:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import json

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', type=json.loads)
parser.parse_args(['-l', '[[1,2],["foo","bar"],[3.14,"baz",20]]'])
```

prints:

```
Namespace(l=[[1, 2], ['foo', 'bar'], [3.14, 'baz', 20]])
```

Comment: And you might need escaping the quotes when actually calling your program from bash