# Passing a list into one kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, python-fire

The final idea is to start my python program with a command like :
`python.exe -m myProgram execute --tags arg1 arg2 arg3`
I'm trying to get "arg_1", "arg_2", ..., "arg_n" (with n unknown) inside a list and access all of them thanks to "tags"

I tried some ways like :

```
def run(self, **kwargs) -> None:
    tags = []
    for arg in kwargs.values():
        tags = tags.append(kwargs.get("tags", None))
    print(tags)
```

Or :

```
def run(self, **kwargs) -> None:
    tags = kwargs.get("tags", None)
```

But I can't get expected result.
Should I change my command or does it exist a way to get tags like a list ?
Please, any help ?
Thank you

Comment: What are you using to get the input parameters?

Comment: You might want to look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-with-argparse

Comment: Use the argument parser that comes with python [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse). In particular `nargs='*'`. Is there any reason to have `--tags` at all? Consuming all items in the argument list seems like `--tags` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll read all of it. 
@AChampion, I may need to add other param with other names. ```--tags``` was an exemple.
@Riccardo, thank you for the link. Looking for ```kwargs```, I didn' find/think to ```argparse```.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok,
I found how to do :
`python.exe -m myProgram execute --tags=[arg1,arg2,arg3]`
This format created the list I wanted to send to my program.
Anyway, your links was interesting to read. Thanks again.