# How to have multiple args for a single option in argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I would like to allow a user to enter in multiple `ids` as an argument. For example, something like:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dedupe assets based on group_id.')
parser.add_argument('--ids', nargs='?', default=None, type=int, help='Enter your ids')
parser.parse_args()
```

Yet when I enter in something like:

```
$ python test.py --ids 1 2 3 4
```

I get the following error:

> `test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 2 3 4`

What would be the proper way to allow/enter in multiple arguments for a single option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a list as a command-line argument with argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-with-argparse)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Oh, I see. nargs is lazy so I need to do `+` instead of `?`.

Comment: '?' is `optional' (0 or 1), '+' is 1 or more, etc.  It tries to follow `regex` conventions where it makes sense.  Look at 'nargs/?' in the docs for more details.

Comment: @hpaulj oh I was mixing up `?` and `*` (0 or more). Is `*` supported by nargs ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use '+' rather than '?'.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dedupe assets based on group_id.')
parser.add_argument('--ids', nargs='+', default=None, type=int, help='Enter your ids')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.ids)
```