# Passing array as a function argument

Tags: python, arrays, string, function, user-input

I want to pass an empty array from main function to a user defined function  and inside that function the inputs will be taken into the array from the user and the array will return to the main function when called. The inputs will be in string.

I am new to Python. Can someone please show me how to write this code in Python?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is quite broad. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-with-argparse

Comment: Why would you want to pass an empty array?

Comment: I cant upload an image I need 10 reputations :(.

Comment: I want the inputs to be taken in the user defined function and then return the array to the main function

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hard question to answer without an example, but I will try my best. So let's say you want to call a function `create_list` and have it make your list. You could do it a few ways. This first example is how you could create the list inside of the `create_list`.

```py
def create_list(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    result = []
    result.append(arg1)
    result.append(arg2)
    result.append(arg3)
    # Or whatever the code is to generate the list
    return result

my_list = create_list("Hello", "world", "!")

print(my_list)
```

Alternatively, you could create a list in your main function and have `create_list` modify it.

```py
def create_list(list_arg, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    list_arg.append(arg1)
    list_arg.append(arg2)
    list_arg.append(arg3)
    # Or whatever the code is to generate the list

my_list = []

create_list(my_list, "Hello", "world", "!")

print(my_list)
```

There are many other ways to do this depending on what you are looking for exactly but those are the most basic and will work in a majority of cases.

Comment: Could you please correct the line(s) that is wrong in this following code: https://pastebin.pl/view/9023a6f9

Comment: That link does not work for me for some reason. Either way, Stack Overflow is generally not for asking someone to fix code, but to ask questions so that you can learn how to fix it yourself.