# Parser takes only first character from the filename and says "File not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-arguments

I know it's very difficult to understand my issue, but I'll try my best to explain.
So I've cloned a repository from Github and working on it.
When I run the program without any arguments, it works fine
`python main.py --audio` works fine.
But when I try to pass my own file, it shows an error.
`python main.py --audio myaudio.wav` shows an error saying "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<File Path/m'"
Notice how it only takes the first character from my argument?
In the code, for default mode, it's something like:
(args.py)`parser.add_argument('--audio', default=['default_audio.wav'], type=list)` and it works fine.
So naturally, I tried to add '[]' to my file name
`python main.py --audio [myaudio.wav]` Shows an error too which says "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<File Path/['"
See, here it took only the first character of my provided argument i.e. '['
And the file IS there. No spelling mistakes in file name either.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Advait. Is there any way that you could add a link to the repository, so that we can have a closer look? I suspect that this is a bug in the code. See this comprehensive answer [How can I pass a list as a command-line argument with argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753721/8106583)

Comment: @wuerfelfreak Here's the repository: github.com/vbelz/Speech-enhancement. I am working on the 'prediction' part of this project.

Comment: Try changing the code to `parser.add_argument('--audio', default=['default_audio.wav'], nargs='+')`. This indeed looks like a bug in the software that needs to be fixed. I see that you have already opened an issue on Github.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak Oh wow! It worked! I CANNOT thank you enough for this. ^_^