# Passing multiple sets of arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'm working on a project where I need a company name and a related number as inputs for my script.

An example of this would be as follow:
`python myscript.py "Company 1" 5`

The above works fine for a single company but I'd like to add multiple at the same time (not limited to 3) like this:
`python myscript.py "Company 1" 5 "Company 2" 9 "Company 3" 15`

I've been searching but I have the feeling `argparse` does not support this feature and I'm not sure where to look next.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-with-argparse
Look into the append functionality.

Comment: Or if you need the pairs to be separate arguments, see [Handling indefinite paired arguments with argparse](/q/17126062/4518341), although the only answer is to do it manually.

Comment: @Blue Where does that cover pairs of arguments? I skimmed it but didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: You get most control over the parsing when using `optionals`, flagged arguments.  Otherwise parsing strictly by position, and there's nothing in your input to identify "sets".  To the parser your input is just a long list of strings,which it can handle with `nargs='*'`.  But that's no different from parsing `sys.argv` directly.