# Pass list as argument to Python from Bash script

Tags: python, string, bash, list, arguments

I would like to pass a list of strings as an argument to a Python script.

I have a bash script `bash_script.sh` like:

```
local dtype=float32
declare -a tokens
tokens=("CLS", "HI")
    
python -m python_script.py --langs abc --tokens ${tokens[@]} --dtype $dtype
```

The python script `python_script.py` being called is:

```
def parse_args():
    """Parse CLI arguments"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Do something')
    parser.add_argument('--langs', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--tokens', type=list, required=False)
    parser.add_argument('--dtype', type=str, default='float16')

def main(args):
    """Handle CLI args"""
    print(args.padding_tokens)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(parse_args())
```

However, when I run `bash bash_script.sh`, I get the error: `__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: HI`

I have also tried to do

```
declare -a padding_tokens
padding_tokens=("CLS, HI")
```

and then passing `$padding_tokens[@]` into the Python script from the Bash script, but still get the same error.

How can I pass the list of strings as an argument to a Python script from a Bash script, and then process the list of strings in the Python script from the `args`?

Comment: Hi, tried looking here? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-with-argparse

Comment: Try putting double quotes around the argument to prevent [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), like this: `"${tokens[@]}"`.