# Creating a list from a ini file and parsing it

Tags: python, list, parsing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a script which will read a .ini file. Into the .ini file there are multiple lines starting with a certain word: "word". (I do not know if every time I have more or less than 4 lines). after the "word" keyword there will be more paths to another files, something like this:

```
word = c:\Users\bgandul\PycharmProjects\trial01\notepad\trial01.txt
word = c:\Users\bgandul\PycharmProjects\trial01\notepad\trial02.txt
word = c:\Users\bgandul\PycharmProjects\trial01\notepad\trial03.txt
word = c:\Users\bgandul\PycharmProjects\trial01\notepad\trial04.txt
```

Inside of these files there are some words (does not matter); Let's suppose we have the following situation:

- into the trial01.txt we have the following words: "Mary has"
- into the trial02.txt we have "green apples"
- into the trial03.txt we have "and"
- into the trial04.txt we have "five oranges"

From command line interpreter I wish to be able to have the following output:

**Mary has green apples and five oranges**

Just to recall, does not matter how many paths there are. The script should concatenate the information from those trialxx.txt files (even there are only 2 files or 100 files)

Up to now I did the following:

```
def commandlineinitializer(path1):
    path1 = "C:\\Users\\bgandul\\PycharmProjects\\trial01\\config.ini"
    my_list = []
    word = 'word'
    with open(path1) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(word):
                my_list.append(line)
    new_list = []
    for item in my_list:
        remove_prefix = item.removeprefix('word = ')
        remove_sufix = remove_prefix.removesuffix('\n')
        new_list.append(remove_sufix)
    print("new_list:", new_list)


argpath = sys.argv[1]

commandlineinitializer(argpath)
```

and now, the last list "new_list" I would like to parse it, and starting from here I am stucked.

I have read some answers from here: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-with-argparse", but I cannot understand to much.

Comment: Do the `trial0n.txt` files only contain 1 line? If not, what should happen?

Answer (score 1):

For the example data (one line per `trialXY.txt` file) the following should produce the required output:

```
def func(path):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        print(file.read().rstrip(), end=" ")

WORD = "word"
def get_paths(ini_file_path):
    with open(ini_file_path, "r") as file:
        return [
            line.split("=")[1].strip() for line in file if line.startswith(WORD)
        ]

ini_file_path = "C:\\Users\\bgandul\\PycharmProjects\\trial01\\config.ini"
for path in get_paths(ini_file_path):
    func(path)
```

If you want to pack it into a script file `script.py` and do

```
$: python script.py <your ini-file path here>
```

then you could do

```
import sys

def func(path):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        print(file.read().rstrip(), end=" ")

WORD = "word"
def get_paths(ini_file_path):
    with open(ini_file_path, "r") as file:
        return [
            line.split("=")[1].strip() for line in file if line.startswith(WORD)
        ]

ini_file_path = sys.argv[1]
for path in get_paths(ini_file_path):
    func(path)
```

or use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType

def func(path):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        print(file.read().rstrip(), end=" ")

WORD = "word"
def get_paths(ini_file):
    return [
        line.split("=")[1].strip() for line in ini_file if line.startswith(WORD)
    ]

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("ini_file", type=FileType("r"))
args = parser.parse_args()

for path in get_paths(args.ini_file):
    func(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. To be honest, I think I need something else, but my formulation was not so good. 

for example if there is a function with **one** parameter and the parameter have to be the paths from the config.ini file. How can be called a function for a certain numbers of times depending how many lines there are? thanks :)

Comment: @BGandul So instead of printing the files on the prompt you want to call a function for each path in the ini-file (with the resp. path as argument)?

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is what I would like to do.

Comment: @BGandul See my edit, but I'm still not sure if I understand correctly. Is the function you want to call defined inside the module or imported, or do you want to call a function outside of Python?