# How to pass a list of 2d arguments to Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

The use case is I have a list of x,y coordinates that I display in a matplotlib graph.  I hard coded the values as below to get it to work.

The code I was using is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse  #added in later

data = np.array([[1,4], [2,2], [4,7], [6,3]])
x,y = data.T
print (data)
```

Which works, so I tried to add in argparse in order to make it dynamic with n(arguments) and take out the hard coded values:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()
```

after passing in arguments in many variations of the following:

```
python multi_point.py ([[1,4], [2,2], [4,7], [6,3]])
```

I keep getting errors relating to this structure as a "namespace" and not an iterable?

However, I don't know if it's the wrong library for this or my terminal syntax is wrong or something else? Btw, I'm using VSCode as my IDE and running it on a terminal.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a list as a command-line argument with argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-with-argparse)

Comment: Command line arguments are strings. You need to specify how you want them to be parsed, either by configuring an appropriate `ArgumentParser` argument or by processing the string after parsing CLI arguments.

Comment: Commandline and `argparse` is not a good way to enter data like this.  Besides being a pain to type, you have to quote everything so the shell does not split on spaces.  `nargs='*'` can accept a plain list of strings/numbers but not '[]'.  I'd recommend putting that data in a file, and specify the file name in the commandline.

Comment: Yep, I agree, but I don't know how many params will be passed in.  If it's more than a few I'll use a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ast to parse string literals to your python program :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import ast  # added to parse the string representation of the list

# Define the command-line argument
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('data', type=str, help='List of lists representing data points')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Parse the string representation of the list into a Python list
data = ast.literal_eval(args.data)
data = np.array(data)

x, y = data.T
print(data)
```

You will still need to wrap your argument in doublequotes because of the spaces :

```
python test.py "[[1,4], [2,2], [4,7], [6,3]]"
```

Which should output :

```
[[1 4]
 [2 2]
 [4 7]
 [6 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I was spending way too much on this not realizing the ints had to be converted.